# how to push new view when a cell is tapped in tableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

how to push new view when a cell is tapped in tableview ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: This might be your first time using SO. You need to first describe your problem, and then use the Code tags to describe your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Many will try to help you, but you could make it easier for them.
**First**, look how your question is formatted; this in no way optimal: Please don’t submit your code as an image, but as text, formatted as code (look at the top bar, where you enter your question).
**Next**, when your delegate method `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is called, you want to present a new view controller, apparently by pushing it onto the stack of a navigation controller. This segue has apparently be defined in storyBoard and was named „CellViewController“. You could check if iOS tries to execute this segue by implementing in your view controller

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender;
```

and set a breakpoint there. So you would know at least if iOS tries to present your view controller.
**Eventually**, I suggest to set an exception breakpoint: In the breakpoint pane of Xcode, tap at the + sign bottom left, and enable exception breakpoints. Then, any exception will halt execution of your code where an exception occurs. This allows you to investigate the reason.